# prevent event bubbling in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event as

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn1', function(e){
   alert('clicked');
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   return false;
   alert('clicked again');
});
```

However, the clicked again is always showing.

Even after the `return false;` the click event is executing again.

How can i ensure a 1 time execution.

Comment: That is impossible... That alert is unreachable.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't understand what "event bubbling" means. See http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `one()` instead

```
$(document).one('click', '#btn1', function(e){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

[one documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: This might or might not be what the OP wants... It's worth pointing out that this will remove the `click` handler after the first click.  It does NOT prevent the event bubbling up.

Comment: No it doesn't. But i think the OP misinterpreted what bubbling up means. Additionally i included a link to the official documentation so that the OP could evaluate whether it was the right solution for their issue.